# How can I replace the default checkbox icon in MudBlazor Table?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, mudblazor

Im using **MudBlazor** Table , but i wanna replace the default **CheckBox** by another one .
by turning MultiSelection="true" it display the checkboxes

```html
                <MudTable Dense="true" Hover="true" Bordered="true" MultiSelection="true" Items="@Elements" FixedHeader="true" Striped="true" HeaderClass="table-head-bordered" FooterClass="table-foot-bordered">
                    <ToolBarContent>
                        <MudSpacer />
                        <MudTablePager PageSizeOptions="new int[]{5,10,25,50,100}" />
                    </ToolBarContent>
                    <HeaderContent>
                        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Number)">Nr</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
                        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Sign)">Sign</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
                        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel InitialDirection="SortDirection.Ascending" SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Name)">Name</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
                        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Position)">Position</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
                        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Molar)">Mass</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
                    </HeaderContent>
                    <RowTemplate>
                        <MudTd DataLabel="Nr">@context.Number</MudTd>
                            <MudTd DataLabel="Sign">@context.Sign</MudTd>
                            <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Name</MudTd>
                            <MudTd DataLabel="Position">@context.Position</MudTd>
                            <MudTd DataLabel="Molar mass">@context.Molar</MudTd>
                        </RowTemplate>
                        <PagerContent>
                            <MudTablePager PageSizeOptions="new int[]{5,10,25,50,100}" />
                        </PagerContent>
 </MudTable>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you want to change it to?

Comment: @RBee i have an svg file already , cause  the default MudCheckbox give you that option and i already did that , but when it comes to the table i couldn''t

Comment: you can't replace the entire component, but if you just want to change the styles then you can override the checkbox CSS classes

Comment: @RBee i will try this first , thank you

Comment: @RBee sadly , replacing the css won't work , cause they are using an svg for the checkbox and i need to replace that

Comment: at the end i will follow this approach  <MudTd > <CustomMudCheckbox></CustomMudCheckbox></MudTd> , the customMudCheckbox is a checkbox i created based on MudCheckbox , thank you for your time